# get like status using JS SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

how can i get the page like status using FB JS SDK? i have done this in php sdk. i just cant figure it out on JS.
i currently have this block of codes:

> var session = FB.getSession();
>   FB.api({
>       method: 'fql.query',
>        query: 'SELECT uid, page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=' + session.uid + ' AND 
>   page_id=188073501230086'
>      },
>     function(response) {
>         if(response instanceof Array && response.length > 0)
>             alert("YOU LIKE US!");
>         else
>             alert("YOU DON'T LIKE US YET!");
>     }

I'm really so newb when it comes to javascript, so i really dont know what i am missing. do i have to include some js files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FB.api({
method: 'fql.query',
query: 'SELECT uid, page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND page_id=188073501230086'
},
function(response) {
if(response instanceof Array && response.length > 0) {
alert("YOU LIKE US!");
} else {
alert("YOU DON'T LIKE US YET!");
});
```

Works fine for me. I liked your page (http://www.facebook.com/pages/Alarm-Data-Security/188073501230086?sk=wall) ran that code and it worked. You need to make sure that you have permissions for that user though by calling FB.getLoginStatus like so:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(c){ 
if (c.status == "connected") { 
/* run query */ 
} else { 
/* call FB.login() then run query */
}
});
```

Comment: james, you said my code is already working.. how come i dont get any alert XD